# Returning edge list from Neo4j cypher query

Tags: r, neo4j, cypher, igraph

Hi I have recently started using Neo and wanted to know how I can query a graph to return two columns of IDs showing connections.

```
MATCH path=(s1:Student{StudentId: 7079945})-[r:FRIENDS*6..9]->(s2:Student)
WHERE  s1.StartDate> '2015-01-01' 
RETURN s1.StudentID, s2.StudentId
```

The above gives me all the connection for s1 however It doesn't show any other connections.  How can I collect all of the connections in this graph into one edge list?  The plan is to use this query in RNeo4j and analyse with igraph.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are literally just interested in the pairs of nodes in each path then you could do something like the following.

This query takes the matched paths, groups the pairs of nodes in each path and then only returns the distinct pairs.

```
MATCH path=(s1:Student{StudentId: 7079945})-[r:FRIENDS*6..9]->(s2:Student)
WHERE  s1.StartDate> '2015-01-01'
WITH REDUCE(pairs =[],r in relationships(path) | pairs + [[startNode(r).StudentId,endNode(r).StudentId]]) as pairs
UNWIND pairs as pair
WITH DISTINCT pair
RETURN pair[0] as from, pair[1] as to
```

Comment: Thanks for the response I think this is on the right track but it just returns the graph.  However I only want to return two columns of corresponding IDs

Comment: np - I updated it to just return the student id in discrete columns. Aside... is your handle a Top Gear nod? If so... nicely done.

Comment: btw... if you get a graph back in the browser and you want to see what the actual rows are you can always click the "Rows" icon on the left side of each query pane. You can toggle back with the "Graph" icon just above.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to return the path

```
MATCH path=(s1:Student{StudentId: 7079945})-[r:FRIENDS*6..9]->(s2:Student)
WHERE  s1.StartDate> '2015-01-01' 
RETURN path
```

As you are probably not interested in returning :FRIENDS relationship, because they are all the same you can return only nodes of the path

```
MATCH path=(s1:Student{StudentId: 7079945})-[r:FRIENDS*6..9]->(s2:Student)
WHERE  s1.StartDate> '2015-01-01' 
RETURN nodes(path)
```

You can find more functions for path in [documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/).

Comment: I still get back the same graph, i'm just trying to get two columns of studentIDs showing connections so that I can use them in `visNetwork(nodes, edgelist)` in R after changing the col names to 'from' and 'to'.  Basically and edgelist for this graph.  I'm following https://neo4j.com/blog/visualize-graph-with-rneo4j/